# Store values from table for use in later tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, selenium3

Below is my HTML code. I need to be able to save the names in the table rows (Saurav P, Ranjit M) to use in later tests.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Case managers who sign forms for this Case" width="100%" class="TableStyle">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="25" id="PARAHDR" style="padding-left:0px">
                <table style="border:none 0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="PARAHDR" style="width:3px">
                                <!--<IMG src='../images/icons/dash_lt_end_7.gif'>-->
                            </td>
                            <td id="PARAHDR">Case managers who sign forms for this Case</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="LISTHDR" align="LEFT" width="2%" valign="TOP">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="LISTHDR" align="LEFT" width="98%" valign="TOP">Name </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="TBLROW1">
            <td class="TDOCLIST">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="TDOCLIST">&nbsp;Saurav P&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="TBLROW2">
            <td class="TDOCLIST">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="TDOCLIST">&nbsp;Ranjit N&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I use Selenium to find the names and save them into a global variable that I can use later?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of names in the list, or a way to store all the names in the list for later?

Comment: @KatePaulk I am trying to get the names and store as variable ex: Saurav P, Ranjit N. I can use the variables to match in other pages. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated your question with this information - this makes it clearer to others what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

```
// Find all rows with a class with TBLROW as sub-string
List<WebElement> rowsWithName = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class*=\"TBLROW\"]"));  
List<String> names = rowsWithName.stream().map(row -> // For each row
                        row.findElements(By.className("TDOCLIST")) // Find all TDOCLIST cells
                           .get(1) // Get the second one
                           .getText()) // And extract its text
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Afterwards, gather all texts in a list
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. One note, it requires JDK 8 or higher (streams).

Comment: @João Farias Dint work either.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer i got, which is matching exactly what i wanted:

```
List<WebElement> allText = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"));

        int total = allText.size();
        System.out.println(total);
        for(int i=3;i<=total;i++){
            CaselevelSigningCMs =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pnlLeftMenu']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr"+"["+i+"]"+"/td[2]")).getText();
            System.out.println(CaselevelSigningCMs);
            }
```